# How to subtract two shapes in wpf programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drawing, shapes

I am new in wpf and I am trying to create simple shape that will be combination of two shapes (rectangle and ellipse). I want to have rectangle with a hole in a middle. How to achieve this programmatically when user clicks on a button, not in XAML.

Comment: Use a Path with a [CombinedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.combinedgeometry.aspx).

Comment: Suppose you have tried to do something. Now, you must tell us where do you stuck.

Comment: Well I have two shapes, Rectangle and Ellipse inside that Rectangle, just basic drawing in wpf, only I haven't used XAML but code. I just wont to know if there is a way to use that Ellipse inside Rectangle to cut hole (subtract one shape from another). I have done this in Qt creator under linux, now I have to do the same in wpf, but not sure how.

Comment: CombinedGeometry works for me. Thanks Clemens